# I have columns origin and destination and gdsname, and need to count the number of distinct entries from origin to destination group by gdsname

Tags: sql

I have columns of origin, destination, sourcemedia and gdsname,

Now, I need to count number of entries from origin to destination with sourcemedia (its common for all origin to destination)
and gdsname-wise (as the gdsname is different for different routes)

Comment: Your description is very unclear. Please show sample input, expected outcome, what you have tried so far and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: take the [tour] read [ask] and post a [mcve]